# Why is my dwarf in a fey mood but not claiming a workshop?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

One of my dorfs is in a strange mood, and she refuses to leave her room...

I'm a very new DF player so I know she wants something, but am unsure as to WHAT they want...

I know a fey mood usually means once they reach a workshop I'll know, but they don't go to one.

They do have modest quarters and locked themselves in there. this is the furthest I have ever gotten, so please help!
[image]
Also I did just add them to my military, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your dwarf isn't claiming a workshop, it usually means that she's looking for a workshop you haven't built. The fact that she is "unfocused after being unable to practice a craft" also seems to suggest that you're missing the right workshop for her.

Look at her skills for a hint of what she might want. Is she a competent gem setter? Then you'll probably have to build a jeweler's workshop.

Comment: Right, I just had to create a leather works. thanks!